# selenium: How to select a button to click , if the same button already exists on the same page with same name,value,id?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

actually this button open on the popup, but exist in the same page .
![enter image description here][1]

I tried to read the `.... ' with the below code

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("td")).findElement(By.id("leadCaptureList_leadCaptureList_assignCampaign")).click();
```

but its showing error like "Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"leadCaptureList_leadCaptureList_assignCampaign"}"

Comment: Provide, html of the overlay. I believe xpath, cssSelector should do your job.

Comment: @Husam i update my above code

Comment: First get the parent popup div element and then inside it search for the 'Assign Campaign' btn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other button is not in a td, then you can use following code.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/input[@id='leadCaptureList_leadCaptureList_assignCampaign']")).click();
```

On the other hand, if both have same xpath as well, then you can use index with xpath as follows:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//td/input[@id='leadCaptureList_leadCaptureList_assignCampaign'])[1]")).click(); //you will have to give the correct index, I am giving [1] as example
```

If this doesn't work as well (which I doubt), then I'll need the 2nd button's html as well, to find out the difference between two button.

Answer (score -1):

Just like Husam said, add parent to the selector, such as the div popped up.
`//assume popup div id is popup`
`$("#popup #button").click()` may be the one you want.

Hopes this helps